# Concatenate each line of two textboxes recursively

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two textboxes  that read from a text file. I want to try to recursively concatenate the two in a way that each value from **textbox 1** will get concatenated with EVERY value in **textbox 2** separated with a delimiter, such as in the example below:

**Textbox 1**

```
user1

user2

user3

user4

user5
```

**Textbox 2**

```
id1

id2

id3
```

**I want the output to be like this:**

```
user1,id1

user1,id2

user1,id3

user2,id1

user2,id2

user2,id3
```

and so on...

Any idea how to do this? It's for a personal program I am making for myself to make my life easier for my business. I don't have much programming experience and so  it is a bit difficult for me.

I already know how to save the output to another file and fill the textbox 1 and 2 with values from a text file, I'm just struggling with this last part.

**My code for filling the two textboxes**

```
// Read files and fill lists
private void listOneBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {                
        string read = File.ReadAllText(openFile.FileName);
        list1 = read;
        listOneBox.Text = list1;
    }
}

private void listTwoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {               
        string read = File.ReadAllText(openFile.FileName);                
        list2 = read;
        listTwoBox.Text = list2;
    }
}
```

**Edit: This is what my program looks like:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is this webforms?

Comment: what you tried so far? show us your attempt, where did you stuck? how are you reading file and assigning values to text box? Is it webform, wpf, winforms?

Comment: @seesharper It's Windows Forms app

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar  I'm using files        string read = File.ReadAllText(openFile.FileName);
                
                listOneBox.Text = read;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    string textbox1 = @"user1
user2
user3
user4
user5";

    string textbox2 = @"id1
id2
id3";

    string[] Split(string text) =>
        text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    string[] result
        = Split(textbox1).SelectMany(x => Split(textbox2), (x, y) => $"{x},{y}").ToArray();
```

That gives me:

```
user1,id1 
user1,id2 
user1,id3 
user2,id1 
user2,id2 
user2,id3 
user3,id1 
user3,id2 
user3,id3 
user4,id1 
user4,id2 
user4,id3 
user5,id1 
user5,id2 
user5,id3
```

Comment: Not quite sure how to apply this to my code,  I have edited my question to show my code and an image of my program

Comment: @ezcujstom - You would either replace `textbox1` with `listOneBox.Text` or `list1` and `textbox2` with `listTwoBox.Text` or `list2`. The code and the image you posted does not show what you're doing with the final list of strings (i.e. the `result` array in my code).

Comment: I see, I haven't done anything with the final list of strings yet because I wasn't sure how. All i did so far is fill both textboxes with data from files

Comment: @ezcujstom - You asked for "I want the output to be like this" - which is what I've done. Perhaps you need to be clearer on how you want to use the output?

Comment: Oh no you did fine! I was just saying that I hadn't gotten this far in my own program

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void rec1(string[] strBox1, string[] strBox2, int i)
        {
            if (i < strBox1.Length)
            {
                rec2(strBox1[i], strBox2, 0);
                rec1(strBox1, strBox2, i+=1);
            }
        }
        static void rec2(string str, string[] strBox2, int j)
        {


            if (j < strBox2.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str.Trim() + "," + strBox2[j].Trim());
                rec2(str, strBox2, j +=1);
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var txtBox1 = listOneBox.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by ENTER '\n'
            var txtBox2 = listTwoBox.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            rec1(txtBox1, txtBox2, 0);

        }
```

Comment: Don't use `'\n'` - you should use `Environment.NewLine`. It's there to ensure that your code runs on any environment.

Comment: I get 'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Split'

Comment: you can use this TextBox.Text.Split(........) if your text is from a TextBox

Comment: in your example it's like this : listOneBox.Text.Split(........)